# Default axis ranges are different for bars and lines in Plotly for R

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am having trouble understanding the default axis range for bars and lines in plotly for R. They seem to be different. To be precise, the default y-axis range for bars is not based on the extrema of the input data while it is based as such for lines. A little bit of background follows.

So I am making a plot of different economic time series. As is often the case with visualization of economic data, I often need two y-axes to show different variables which might be related. Currently I am making a line chart on the primary y axis and a bar chart on the secondary axis. The problem is that the secondary axis bar chart does not adequately represent the data because it selects a very wide range for the axis on a default basis. E.g. the specific variable on the sec. axis ranges from 3500 to 4000 but the range is shown from 0 to 4000. For line charts there is no such problem. 
I can of course change these ranges manually using the attribute "range" in the the "layout" function but I want to be able to get my desired plot without much manual input. Also, it is helpful if plotly figures out the extrema by itself because the input data changes quite frequently. Here is my current code:

```
plot_ly(data = filter(dlx_df3, month_date >= "2013-01-01", month_date <= "2014-01-01")) %>% 
  add_lines(x = ~month_date,y = ~walr, name = "walr") %>% 
  add_bars(x = ~ month_date,y =  ~ advances,yaxis = "y2", name  = "adv") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(ticks = "outside"),
    yaxis2 = list(
      side = "right",
      autotick = TRUE,
      ticks = "outside",
      rangemode = "normal"
    ),
    yaxis = list(
      overlaying = "y2",
      autotick = TRUE,
      ticks = "outside"
    ),
    legend = list(x = 1.08, y = 0.7)
  )
```

[image: This is the plot that is produced from the code above]

You can see that the bars do not show much "variation". But this changes if I change the add_bars to add_lines. See below:
[image: Plot after changing the secondary axis trace to line from bars]

How do I change this axis modification for bars?

Comment: Could you provide some data?

Comment: Hello, I am having the same problem and a link to the question is here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052883/secondary-axis-in-ploty-for-r-and-shiny